# Can JavaScript detect the Arc browser?

Tags: javascript, browser-detection, arc-browser

The [Arc](https://arc.net/) browser is a new browser which used the Chromium engine and identifies itself as Chrome using a user agent string like this: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Can JavaScript tell the difference between Arc and Chrome/Chromium? There must be something different about it.

Comment: Not necessarily. Most browsers only include the generic user agent string in order to reduce fingerprinting. That said, if Arc puts specific variables or changes the global variables in some specific way, it could be done... but would be more difficult to figure out what those differences may be (and they could change it in future versions). Also, browsers devs are hoping to get rid of the user agent in the future. In the end, it's best not to try fingerprinting users and stick to feature detection for API availability.

Comment: @Jim I fully agree. My intention is to understand what browsers are being used by my audience in order to provide the best experience for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Arc-specific CSS variable `--arc-palette-title` that you can check for:

```
console.log(
    getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--arc-palette-title') ? 'Is Arc' : 'Is Not Arc'
);
```

Note: does not work while page is still loading.