How to detect Arc Browser with extension?
I'm trying to implement Arc Browser detection for ActivityWatch so the recorded browsing data would be categorised correctly.
Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/ActivityWatch/aw-watcher-web/issues/118

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/76123404, you can detect Arc Browser by specific CSS value:
console.log(
    getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--arc-palette-title') ? 'Is Arc' : 'Is Not Arc'
);

It works fine on regular websites, as I've tried it myself.

However, this doesn't work properly if the code is run from extension — the CSS value isn't present there.
Is there any other way to detect Arc Browser from extension?
